# How do I get all pages of a paginated response in a Power Query query that also uses parameters?

Tags: rest, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to get all pages of the API responses using Power Query Editor for Power BI Desktop, but have run into some problems getting the query to run.

I've used [This tutorial](https://medium.com/@marktiedemann/how-to-do-pagination-in-power-query-430460c17c78) as a starting point (but am open to suggestions).

## The Problem

Currently, when I invoke this function from the table with the ext_id, to, and from parameters, I get an Expression.Error that The parameter is expected to be of type Text.Type or Binary.Type.

All I want to do is get all the pages of the query. The pages are available in the response at reviews.page.total.

I'm also trying to be as efficient as possible, as AppFollow uses a credit-based "payment" system for transacting with the API. Can someone help figure out where I've gone wrong?

## My Current Code

```
(ext_id as text, from as text, to as text) =>
let
    BaseURL     = "https://api.appfollow.io/api/v2/reviews?",
    token       = "[redacted]",
    Query       = "ext_id=" & ext_id & "&from=" & from & "&to=" & to,

    GetJson = (Url) =>
        let 
            Options     = [Headers=[Accept="application/json", #"X-AppFollow-API-Token"= token ]],
            RawData     = Web.Contents(Url, Options),
            Json        = Json.Document(RawData)
        in  Json,

    GetPageCount = () =>
        let Url             = BaseURL & Query,
            response        = GetJson(Url),
            toJson          = Json.Document(response),
            total           = toJson[reviews]{0}[page][total]
        in  total,

    GetPage = (Index) =>
        let
            Page    = "&page=" & (Index),
            Url     = BaseURL & Query & Page,
            Json    = GetJson(Url),
            Value   = Json[reviews]
        in  Value,

    PageCount       = GetPageCount(),
    PageIndicies     = {0..PageCount -1},
    Pages           = List.Transform(PageIndicies, each GetPage(_)),
    Results         = List.Union(Pages),

#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromRecords(Results)

in
#"Converted to Table"
```

## Sample Response

```
{
    "query": "/api/reviews?cid=[cid-here]&ext_id=[ext-id-here&from=2023-01-01&to=2023-01-31&host=global4.appfollow.io&method=GET&real_ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xx",
    "reviews": {
        "list": [
            {
                "data": "[removed data]"
            }
        ],
        "total": 286,
        "page": {
            "current": 1,
            "total": 3,
            "next": 2,
            "prev": null
        },
        "ext_id": "ext-id-here",
        "store": "as"
    }
}
```

## Error Message

```
Expression.Error: The parameter is expected to be of type Text.Type or Binary.Type.
Details:
    query=/api/reviews?ext_id=[ext-id-here]&to=2023-01-31&from=2023-01-01&dev103=1&cid=[cid-here]&host=global4.appfollow.io&method=GET&real_ip=xxx.xx.xxx.xxx
    reviews=[Record]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Page    = "&page=" & Text.From((Index)),
```